# Django redirect does not redirect

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner with Django transaction I use this code to manage my transaction manually :

```
@transaction.commit_manually
@login_required
def delivried_supplier_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'add_ligne' in request.POST:
            cp = request.POST.copy()
            cp['commande_fournisseur_ligne_set-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(cp['commande_fournisseur_ligne_set-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1
            form = CommandeFournisseurForm(request.POST)
            formset = DelivredCmdLigneFormSet(cp)
            transaction.commit()
        else:
            form = CommandeFournisseurForm(request.POST)
            formset = DelivredCmdLigneFormSet(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                try:
                    cmdFournisseur = form.save()
                    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
                    for instance in instances:
                        instance.commande_fournisseur = cmdFournisseur
                        instance.save()
                    transaction.commit()
                    redirect("/inputs/listdelivriedsupplierrequest/")
                except Exception, e:
                    print e
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, e)
                    transaction.rollback()
    else:
        form = CommandeFournisseurForm()
        formset = DelivredCmdLigneFormSet()
        transaction.commit()

    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        forms = [form]
        return render_to_response("inputs/delivredsupplierrequest.html", {
        "formset": formset, "forms": forms
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

All is Ok, but the redirect doesn't work when my data is saved, it always returns to the same page.

Comment: Why aren't you using `reverse()` for your redirect?

Comment: The problem here isn't transactions, it's the `redirect` line. See my answer below. As an aside, what exceptions are you expecting to catch in your try.. except block? Usually the `transaction.commit_on_success` decorator is sufficient, which makes the view simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view isn't returning the response when you call the `redirect` function. So your view continues and you get the default response at the end of the view.

You need to do the following in your view:

```
return redirect("/inputs/listdelivriedsupplierrequest/")
```